# How do you read an archived eventlog file?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Are there any libraries or resources available for parsing/reading an archived eventlogs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is this article [Parsing event log(*.evt) file.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/EventLogParser.aspx?fid=334874&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=2018071#xx2018071xx)
  Then there is the Microsoft [Event Log file format documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb309026(VS.85).aspx) (evt used on xp win 2003).  So far the only information I can find for the new format is a pdf from some [forensic conference.](http://www.dfrws.org/2007/proceedings/p65-schuster.pdf)
And [how to convert evt to evtx](http://blogs.technet.com/askperf/archive/2007/10/12/windows-vista-and-exported-event-log-files.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Which IIS version do you use ? If you use IIS 6, You can use Microsoft Log Parser to see it. Download from [IIS 6 Resource Kit](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/840671)

Comment: Its not so much an IIS thing.  I get sent eventlog archives and need to process them some how.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is .evt, you can just run eventvwr, click Action->Open Log File and select the archived file and the file type.

For programmatic access, there is a .NET class System.Diagnostics.EventLog which would have everything you need.